# How to use map function with condition?

Tags: python

I have a following loop:

```
for i in data.id.unique():
    if i in group.groups.keys():
      main_func(i)
```

How can I use map function in python for multiprocessing, I want to apply the above code in Pool function

```
pool = Pool(processes=5)
pool.map(main_func, group.groups.keys())
```

Comment: pool.map(main_func, [x if x in group.groups.keys() for x in data.id.unique()])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this:

```py
pool = Pool(processes=5)
pool.map(main_func, [i for i in data.id.unique() if i in group.groups.keys()])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a lambda:

```py
pool.map(lambda x: main_func(x) if x in groups.groups.keys() else None, data.id.unique())
```